# Flipswitch widget rendered as dropdown inside external panel widget

Tags: jquery-mobile

I noticed that the flipswitch widget is rendered as dropdown inside a panel, if i put the flipswitch widget inside a page it's rendered as i see in the jQuery mobile demos, is there a way to render it as in the demo?

[image: print screen]

Comment: Sorry, how can someone help You? it should works well in latest stable JQM 1.4.5, What device/browser??? Sadly, w/out showing Your markup/code is just guessing.

Comment: I used latest JQM stable, both on desktop using Firefox and Chrome and also on mobile. Sorry the code is live here: https://theredlips.digitalking.it/giochi/Sx1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized in code Your external panel, but you need also to enhance the the content of the panel.

This should do the trick:

```
<script id="panel-init">
  $(function() {
    $("body>[data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin();
  });
</script>
```

A note aside, just off my head, if you encounter some issues when the panel content is higher than the page size or created dynamically, You may also try to swap the order of enhancements (first enhance the new content, then create the panel) - whatever is best for You, depending from Your markup - or try to invoke `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight()`.

Comment: using

.enhanceWithin();

solved the problem, thank you!